# Can you explain how the pseudopotential method is used to calculate band structures for a senior physics student?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, computational-physics

My senior project is about calculating the band structures using the pseudpotential technique through writing a mathematica code for some materials such GaAs. I have read about the topic and I knew that the technique is an extension to the Orthogonalized Plane wave method (OPW); However, I still feel that I am not fully understand the method either conceptually or mathematically. I want a simple qualitative description of the method that a senior physics student can grasp and be able to start coding.